# jquery.ajax() POST receives empty response with IE10 on Nginx/PHP-FPM but works on Apache

Tags: apache, jquery, character-encoding, nginx, internet-explorer-10

I use a very simple `jquery.ajax()` call to fetch some HTML snippet from a server:

```
// Init add lines button
$('body').on('click', '.add-lines', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : $(this).attr('href')+'?ajax=1&addlines=1',
        data        : $('#quickorder').serialize(),
        success     : function(data,x,y) {
            $('#directorderform').replaceWith(data);
        },
        dataType    : 'html'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

On the PHP side i basically echo out a HTML string. The jQuery version is 1.8.3.

The problem is in **IE10**: While it works fine there on **Server A** which runs on Apache it fails on **Server B** which runs on Nginx + PHP-FPM: If i debug the `success` handler on Server B I get a `undefined` for `data`. In the Network tab of the IE developer tools I can see the full response and all headers. It may affect other IE versions, but i could only test IE10 so far.

Here are the two response headers:

Server A, Apache (works):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 13:28:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1268
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Server B, Nginx + PHP-FPM (fails):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 13:41:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

The body part looks the same in both cases.

Any idea what could cause this issue?

Comment: I remember having some issues with nginx and "chunked" transfer encoding some time ago, may it's worth looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Marian. I also tried that before with `chunked_transfer_encoding off;` in Nginx. No difference. What still puzzles me is the missing `Content-Length` header. It also missing if chunked is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please also check the Content-Type Header, since Apache and Nginx are sending different values:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

vs.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
```

Update your Nginx config, add this line:

```
charset UTF-8;
```

Comment: Unbelievable! This really fixed it. Thanks a lot!